Under the same wifi router, ubuntu 22.04 got ipv6 address, but can't access ipv6 website, while windows 10 works correctly, why?
in my office, I have a TP-LINK wifi router(TPlink TL-WDR7660). The wifi router's WLAN setting is that the ipv4 address of the WLAN port is automatically assigned by the upstream router, while the LAN of ipv4 has a sub-net of 192.168.87.0/24. For the ipv6, it is set as the "bridge" or "pass through" mode(see the document here: How to set up an IPv6 Internet connection on the TP-Link Wi-Fi Routers), so all the ipv6 address and settings are assigned by the upper routers.
Now, if I use a Windows 10 PC to connect the wifi router, I see the PC got both ipv4 and ipv6 address correctly, and I can access or ping some ipv6 site correctly in the Windows 10 PC.
While, I have another PC, which is running Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to connect this Ubuntu to the wifi router, I see it got the ipv6 address correctly. But when I try to ping some ipv6 site, it just returned nothing, so I can't use the Ubuntu to access the ipv6 web site.
Here is the ifconfig command result from the Ubuntu:
wlxcdddddddddd: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.87.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.87.255
        inet6 2001:ddd:dddd:d::d:dddd  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9b9f:7ce6:bd5c:d445  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2019255  bytes 787493044 (787.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2967086  bytes 1884873281 (1.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Note I have change the hex value of the inet6 address to some "dddddd" like chars for security reasons.
Here is the ping result
ping6 he.net
PING he.net(he.net (2001:470:0:503::2)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- he.net ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9216ms

You see, nothing returned from the ping command.
When I run the ip -6 r command, I got such result:
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:ddd:dddd:d::d:dddd dev wlxcdddddddd proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlxcdddddddd proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d dev wlxcdddddddd proto ra metric 20600 pref medium

When I try to pint some broad-cast address, it does return some values, see below:
ping6 -I wlxcddddddddddd ff02::1
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: wlxcddddddddddd
PING ff02::1(ff02::1) from :: wlxcddddddddddd: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::9b9f:7ce6:bd5c:d445%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=541 ms
64 bytes from fe80::9b9f:7ce6:bd5c:d445%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.34 ms
64 bytes from fe80::9b9f:7ce6:bd5c:d445%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms


ping6 -I wlxcddddddddddd ff02::2
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: wlxcddddddddddd
PING ff02::2(ff02::2) from :: wlxcddddddddddd: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=12.0 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.16 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.05 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxcddddddddddd: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.98 ms

My firewall in the Ubuntu is disabled already.
I have also try to disable the "ra" option by the method mentioned here: IPv6 over PPPoe?  But this does not solved my issue.
Any ideas?
I'm not sure why Windows 10 works correctly under the ipv6 network, but Ubuntu 22 just failed.
Thanks.
